# Module Parse Failed For React Table Css

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am having trouble importing this:`import 'react-table/react-table.css';`
I get this error:

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: /Users/andy/Sites/purpose-www/node_modules/react-table/react-table.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

But I have setup the webpack configuration for `css-loader`. Here is my webpack config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }, {
        test: /\.jsx*$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.+\.config.js/],
        loader: 'babel',
      }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Bable.rc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel", "react-html-attrs", "transform-class-properties"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react", "react-optimize", "es2015-native-modules", "stage-0"]
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you test for css twice?

Comment: Have you got .babelrc

Comment: @Aaqib Yes I do, do you need to see it?

Comment: Why are you testing for css twice, removing and including node_modules in these cases?

Comment: That was just included in the mern.io tool. I removed the first one but still didn't work.

Comment: Webpack version ?

Comment: `"2.1.0-beta.8",`

Comment: try replacing `loaders:` with `rules:` inside `modules` , Because everything else to me looks fine